# TF246017: team foundation server could not connect to the database

Tags: tfs

I am facing a problem with logging into TFS. I get the following error:

[image]

> Exception Message: TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect
>   to the database. Verify that the server that is hosting the database
>   is operational, and that network problems are not blocking
>   communication with the server. (type SoapException)SoapException
>   Details:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below thing to narrow down the issue:

- Make sure you are the member of the **Administration Console Users**.
  Otherwise you cannot access the Admin Console.
- Make sure the SQL Server is stated and available, and the network
  connectivity is OK.
- Check the Service Account, make sure the Service Account has been added in
  SQL Server.

You can also refer to the **solution** in below link to fix the issue:
https://www.ganshani.com/alm/tfs/visual%20studio/solved-tf246017-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-the-database/

If above solution can not resolve the problem, please check the Event log. The Windows Event Log is a good candidate where to look for the potential cause.

Answer (score 5):

Hi the below steps worked for me.

Select Application Tier in the TFS Administration Console.

In the Application Tier Summary which contains the Service Account details.

Click Reapply Account.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but here was my situation:
We have 11 collections on our instance, 2 were failing with this error, showing me it wasn't an access / connection issue.  Checking Event Viewer (as @Andy Li-MSFT suggests) showed it was 
`A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'default' (2). Rerun the query.`

Checking task manager showed the culprit - elastic search was using well over 2GB of memory.  I killed the service, the collections applied the patch quickly without issue.
[image]

Looks like I need to ask our server admins to give us a bit more memory....

Comment: You're my hero, god bless you!

Answer (score 0):

For me I've solved the issue by changing the recovery mode Simple -> Full in the database.

Please refer to: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3/sql-server-full-recovery-model/