# Team Foundation Server 2015 Database Error TF:246017

Tags: sql, database, connection, tfs-2015

my tfs console stop working giving error. When i open the tfs administrator console.it works fine a week ago but suddenly start giving this error and my all developers are facing this error.

> TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the instance is specified correctly, that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server.

I have check the databases for the tfs they are working fine means they accept queries and showing result.
also i have checked through command DBCC CHECKDB command and giving zero errors.

kindly help me for this error **I'm new to TFS**

TFS 2015 installed on Windows server 2012 R2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TF246017: team foundation server could not connect to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129042/tf246017-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-the-database)

Comment: @AmitYadav i have tries this but no success. Thanks for reply